# Java Lambda Expression for if condition - not expected here

Tags: java, java-8, lambda

Consider the case where an if condition needs to evaluate an array or a List. A simple example: check if all elements are true. But I'm looking for **generic** way to do it

Normally I'd do it like that:

```
boolean allTrue = true;
for (Boolean bool : bools){
    if (!bool) {
        allTrue = false;
        break;
     }
}
if (allTrue){
     // do Something
}
```

But now I'd like to hide it into my if condition. I tried using Lambda Expressions for this, but it's not working:

```
if (() -> {
    for (Boolean bool : bools)
        if (!bool)
            return false;
    return true;
}){
      // do something
}
```

If this were working I could do something more complicated like

```
if (() -> {
   int number = 0;
   for (MyObject myobject : myobjects)
       if (myObject.getNumber() != 0)
           numbers++;
   if (numbers > 2) 
       return false;
   return true;
 }{
     //do something
 }
```

Is there a better way to do it is it just a syntax error?

**UPDATE**
I'm not talking about the boolean array, rather looking for a generic way to achieve that.

Comment: Uh, use `.anyMatch()`?

Comment: @fge .allMatch () maybe? He wanta to return true if all are true

Comment: Could conceivably use `anyMatch` instead - just `!` the inputs and `!` the whole expression.

Comment: Thx, not aware of those functions. I'm actually looking for a generic way to do it, probably unclear here.

Comment: Uh, your question edit makes things very unclear -- what do you _need_? A count of elements matching a certain predicate?

Comment: @fge I wanted to use a lambda function in my if condition. But haven't been aware of stream functions, very nice new possibilities here.

Comment: Well, a `@FunctionalInterface` is not a `boolean` even if some of them return `boolean`s; you'd have to invoke that "interface" to have a boolean result anyway

Comment: Ok, nice that was the point!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write, given for instance a `List<Boolean>`:

```
if (!list.stream().allMatch(x -> x)) {
    // not every member is true
}
```

Or:

```
if (list.stream().anyMatch(x -> !x)) {
    // at least one member is false
}
```

If you have an *array* of booleans, then use `Arrays.stream()` to obtain a stream out of it instead.

---

More generally, for a `Stream` providing elements of (generic) type `X`, you have to provide a `Predicate<? super X>` to `.{all,any}Match()` (either a "full" predicate, or a lambda, or a method reference -- many things go). The return value of these methods are self explanatory -- I think.

---

Now, to *count* elements which obey a certain predicate, you have `.count()`, which you can combine with `.filter()` -- which *also* takes (whatever is) a `Predicate` as an argument. For instance checking if you have more than 2 elements in a `List<String>` whose length is greater than 5 you'd do:

```
if (list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() > 5).count() > 2L) {
    // Yup...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Your problem

Your current problem is that you use directly a lambda expression. Lambdas are instances of functional interfaces. Your lambda does not have the boolean type, **that's why your `if` does not accept it**.

### This special case's solution

You can use a stream from your collections of booleans here.

```
if (bools.stream().allMatch((Boolean b)->b)) {
    // do something
}
```

It is actually much more powerful than this, but this does the trick I believe.

### General hint

Basically, since you want an `if` condition, you want a `boolean` result.
Since your result depends on a collection, you can use Java 8 streams on collections.

Java 8 streams allow you to do many operations on a collection, and finish with a terminal operation. You can do whatever complicated stuff you want with `Stream`'s non-terminal operations. In the end you need one of 2 things:

- use a terminal operation that returns a `boolean` (such as `allMatch`, `anyMatch`...), and you're done
- use any terminal operation, but use it in a `boolean` expression, such as `myStream.filter(...).limit(...).count() > 2`

You should have a look at your possibilities in [this Stream documentation](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) or [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Comment: This gives a syntax error for me: Incompatible types: cannot infer functional interface descriptor for Predicate<? super boolean[]>